# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6

Tags: eclipse-plugin

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (build-layout) on project igLink: Error reading assemblies: Error locating assembly descriptor: src/assemble/layout.xml
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] [1] [INFO] Searching for file location: Y:\primefaces\workspace\igLink\src\assemble\layout.xml
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] [2] [INFO] File: Y:\primefaces\workspace\igLink\src\assemble\layout.xml does not exist.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] [3] [INFO] File: Y:\primefaces\workspace\igLink\src\assemble\layout.xml does not exist.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: I have included all required plugins

Comment: And your assembly file is located at `Y:\primefaces\workspace\igLink\src\assemble\layout.xml`?